# IIS URL Rewrite domain to one of several VMs

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, rules

I have a server running several Virtual Machines. Each VM runs IIS 8.0 and hosts a variety of different sites.  The base server is also running IIS 8.0 and I'm intending that it directs requests to one of of the VMs depending on the HTTP_HOST.

I'm trying to define the inbound and outbound rules to achieve the following:

```
www.mydomain1.com requests are directed to VM 192.168.1.10/mydomain1

www.mydomain2.com requests are directed to VM 192.168.1.10/mydomain2

www.mydomain3.com requests are directed to VM 192.168.1.11/mydomain3 

www.mydomain4.com requests are directed to VM 192.168.1.11/mydomain4
```

What I want is for the user to see www.mydomainx.com all the time while the internal VM serves up the pages seamlessly without changing the URL.  I've spent hours trying every combination I can think of and read dozens of posts but none seem to cover this particular scenario.

I've got subdomain to folder working (mysub.mydomain.com -> 192.168.1.10/mysub but not full domain name.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: You need ARR for IIS.

Comment: I've got ARR for IIS installed, plus URL Rewrite module.  The question now is how to configure it to achieve the desired result.

Comment: when you download it from IIS.net you should find the documentation there. And the help file is also included in the installation.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching and testing I've finally found the solution.  Instructions below relate to IIS 8.5.

1. Install Application Request Routing Extension for IIS
2. Install URL Rewrite 2.0 for IIS
3. Restart IIS Manager and you should see a new node called Server Farms
4. For every Virtual Machine that hosts websites, create a Server Farm, then add the IP address of the VM as a server in that farm.  In my set up I have one VM per Server Farm.
5. Once you have all your VM's set up in their own Server Farm, select the root server node in IIS and double-click URL Rewrite
6. For each VM create rules for all the domains being handled.

   - Add a new blank rule
   - Add an appropriate name and set the Pattern to .* - regex for all matches
   - In the Conditions section, click Add
   - Set Condition input to {SERVER_NAME}
   - Make sure input string dropdown is set to Matches the Pattern
   - Set the pattern to ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$ - set the domain name appropriately and click ok
   - Add conditions for every domain name that will be handled by the VM
   - In the Action section, set Action Type to Route to Server Farm
   - In the Action properties, select the server farm that will handle these domains
   - Click Apply

Now all you need to do is set up your router to port forward requests on port 80 to your base IIS server and it will then route traffic based on the domain names to the appropriate Virtual Machine.

I have four Virtual Machines set up this way the routing is seamless and works really well.